# how do I solve this question? I have no idea how to solve it cumulative density function

Tags: probability

We produce a random real number X through the following two-stage experiment. First roll a fair die to get an outcome Y in the set {1, 2, . . . , 6}.

Then, if Y = k, choose X uniformly in the interval (0, k]. Find the cumulative distribution function F(s) and the probability density function f(s) of X for 
3 < s < 4

Answer (score 0):

If $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\ldots,6\}$ and $X\mid Y=k$ has uniform distribution on $(0,k)$ then $X$ has density
$$
f_X(x) = \frac16\sum_{k=1}^6\frac1k\mathsf 1_{(0,k)}(x).
$$
We can find the distribution function $F_X(x):= \mathbb P(X\leqslant x)$ by integrating the above, but take care with the limits of integration since $f$ is defined piecewise.

Comment: not (0,k), it is (0,k]

Comment: how you get 1/k????

Comment: The mass at a single point does not matter because $X$ is (piecewise) continuous. And it is because the density of $U(0,k)$ is $\frac1k\mathsf 1_{(0,k)}$.

Comment: how i get the answer???

Comment: integral the whole thing ?

Comment: My prof gave me the hints are sum from k=1 to 6 P(X<=s | Y=k) P(Y=k)

Comment: how we find the probability for P(X<=s| Y=k)???

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As an example, 
$$
P(4<X<4.5) = \frac16 \cdot \frac{0.5}{5} + \frac16 \cdot \frac{0.5}{6}
$$ 
This is because we must roll a 5 or a 6 to get $X>4$. Then the uniform distrubution of $X$ gives $\frac{0.5}{5}$ and $\frac{0.5}{6}$ respectively.

You can use this sort of logic to find $P(X<s)$ for any s, i.e. the CDF. Then differentiate your result to get the PDF.